# How do I make one column of strings in a GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, jframe

I just started learning Java, and I want to make a basic gui that displays the table of 7.

This is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class test {
    private JFrame f;
    private JPanel p;
    private JLabel lab;
    private JLabel lab1;
    private JLabel lab2;

    public test() {
        gui();
    }

    public void gui() {
    {
        f = new JFrame ("table of 7");
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setSize(200,400);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        p = new JPanel();
        p.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

        lab = new JLabel("1 x 7 = 7" );
        lab1 = new JLabel("2 x 7 = 21");
        lab2 = new JLabel("3 x 7 = 28");

        p.add(lab); p.add(lab1); p.add(lab2); 
        f.add(p);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
        new test();
}
}
```

The problem is I want to display the table in a neat column, I have tried /n in a single string but this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

> the problem is I want to display the table in a neat column

They you need to use a monospaced Font.

Maybe something like:

```
label.setFont( new Font("monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 12) );
```

You will need to do this for all your labels.

Or maybe an easier way to display the data is to use a JTextArea then you can do something like:

```
JTextArea textArea - new JTextArea(10, 20);
textArea.setFont(...);
textArea.append("1 x 7 =  7");
textArea.append("\n2 x 7 = 14");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `JTextArea` and set it not editable so it looks like a label and also you can change its background color 
Example :

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
textArea.setEditable(false);
textArea.setBackground(Color.gray.brighter());
textArea.setText("1*7=7\n2*7=14");
```